# What is the correct notation to solve $b^2<32$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$b^2<32$$

You can't just square root both sides, since you'd get $b<\sqrt {32}$ or $b<5.7$
But, clearly $-7$ does not satisfy this since it's too big (absolute value)

What is the correct notation to solve this while taking into account the absolute value must be less than $5.7$ ?

Comment: Why not just $|b|<\sqrt {37}$?

Comment: $b^2 <32 \iff |b| < \sqrt{32} \iff -\sqrt{32} <b< \sqrt{32}.$

Comment: You cannot write this with a rational number. There is no largest rational number with a square less than $32$.

Comment: Lorago..thanks, what is the reasoning this reducing ?

Comment: The inequality $b^2<32$ is equivalent to $b^2-32<0$, which in turn is equivalent to $\left(b-\sqrt{32}\right)\left(b+\sqrt{32}\right)<0$. If we sketch the graph of $y=\left(b-\sqrt{32}\right)\left(b+\sqrt{32}\right)$, we see that it is a U-shaped parabola with roots at $b=-\sqrt{32}$ and $b=\sqrt{32}$. It is between these two points (and these points only) that the value of $y$ is negative. Therefore, $-\sqrt{32}<b<\sqrt{32}$ is the solution to your inequality.

Comment: Formal approach: Case 1: $b \geq 0 \implies \sqrt{b^2} = b.$  Therefore $b < \sqrt{32}.$  Case 2: $b < 0 \implies \sqrt{b^2} = (-b).$  Therefore, $(-b) < \sqrt{32} \implies b > -\sqrt{32}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that

$$b^2<32.$$

Taking square roots you get

$$\sqrt{b^2}=\lvert b\rvert <\sqrt{32}.$$

Now notice that then

$$0\leq \lvert b\rvert<\sqrt{32},$$

which can be expanded into

$$-\sqrt{32}<b<\sqrt{32},$$

which is the answer.